# Braintree.js drop-in , dynamically update client token?

Tags: javascript, braintree

I'm using braintree.js, and loading their drop-in. Everything works fine but I'm unable to submit a second request because a new nonce value is needed.

Everything is done in js- I'm submitting the nonce value and getting a new token. But a new nonce value is returned only with a new client token, so is it possible to update the client token the current loaded form/drop-in is using, without refreshing the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I work as a developer at Braintree. Currently, you cannot dynamically update a client token without a page reload.

This is a known issue and the team is actively working on a solution for a future release. I recommend subscribing to [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/braintree/braintree-web/issues/29) so you will be notified of any pertinent updates.

Comment: There's a work-around:

I'm creating a new iframe, injecting html that includes the form and script setup for braintree with the Client Token using javascript:window["content"] .

Then every callback of braintree's drop-in (onPaymentReceived, onReady, onError) is handled by using Window.postMessage() on the main application window.

Every time you need to create a new drop-in with a different Client Token, you just remove the iframe, and re-create it. This is untested as far as older browsers go but it works perfectly fine on Firefox and Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

You can create the client token by `Braintree Vault` and generate the braintree token and pass it. You can follow this procedure

```
# With this the PaymentMethod will be associated with the Customer
    result = braintree.PaymentMethod.create({
        "customer_id": customer.customer_id,
        "payment_method_nonce": nonce
    })
    token = result.payment_method.token
```